# How can I do a concatenation and also add a 1 to a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this code:

```
 Select 'JFBP' || CC.Number AS NAME, from CC
```

What it does is retrieve rows like this:

```
 JFBP0
 JFBP1
 JFBP2
```

I would like to add a 1 to the numbers so it retrieves

```
 JFBP1
 JFBP2
 JFBP3
```

Can anyone help and explain how I could do this with SQL.  I've tried different combinations but everything seems to get mixed up with the concatenation.

Comment: What does "Select 'JFBP' || (CC.Number + 1) AS NAME, from CC" give you?

Comment: Are you using Sql Server??

Comment: @McMurphy - It gives me what I need.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to append number based on `Number` column by incrementing by 1, then you can do with following query :

```
 Select 'JFBP' || (test_table.Number+1)  AS NAME from test_table
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8e0df/1)

If you want to append number with its row id, then you can use following query :

```
Select 'JFBP' || (rowid)  AS NAME from CC
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8e0df/2)